# C# how to get trailing spaces from the end of a varchar(513) field while exporting SQL table to a flat file

Tags: c#

How do I get empty spaces from the end of a varchar(513) field  while exporting data from SQL table to a flat file. I have a console application. Here is what I am using to export a SQL table having only one column of varchar(513) to a flat file. But I need to get all the 513 characters including spaces at the end.  How do I change this code to incorporate that.

Thanks

```
 {
            var destination = args[0];
            var command = string.Format("Select * from {0}", Validator.Check(args[1]));
            var connectionstring = string.Format("Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI;", args[2]);

            var helper = new SqlHelper(command, CommandType.Text, connectionstring);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destination))
            using (IDataReader reader = helper.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
                    int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        writer.Write(values[i]);

                    writer.WriteLine();
                }

                writer.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to char and nchar which have fixed size and padding spaces at the end, vchar and nvarchar don't. However you can use the `String.PadRight()` function to achieve the same result:

```
writer.Write(values[i].ToString().PadRight(513));
```

Comment: Can I make this generic by getting type and length of each column in the table (any table) and then padright to each column?

Answer (score 1):

`writer.Write{"{0,-513}", values[i])`

Replace -513 with 513 if the space is padded on the left rather than on the right, I never seem to remember which one works :-)